# custom final field for AutoValue with Builder

Tags: auto-value

When using AutoValue with the Builder pattern, how can I initialize other custom final fields in the constructor?

**Example**

```
@AutoValue
abstract class PathExample {

  static Builder builder() {
    return new AutoValue_PathExample.Builder();
  }

  abstract String directory();
  abstract String fileName();
  abstract String fileExt();

  Path fullPath() {
    return Paths.get(directory(), fileName(), fileExt());
  }

  @AutoValue.Builder
  interface Builder {
    abstract Builder directory(String s);
    abstract Builder fileName(String s);
    abstract Builder fileExt(String s);
    abstract PathExample build();
  }

}
```

in the real-world class the initialisation (like in the `fullPath field) is more expensive, so that I want to do it only once. I see 2 ways to do this:

1) lazy initialisation

```
  private Path fullPath;
  Path getFullPath() {
    if (fullPath == null) {
      fullPath = Paths.get(directory(), fileName(), fileExt());
    }
    return fullPath;
  }
```

2) initalisation in the builder

```
private Path fullPath;
Path getFullPath() {
    return fullPath;
}

@AutoValue.Builder
abstract static class Builder {
    abstract PathExample autoBuild();
    PathExample build() {
        PathExample result = autoBuild();
        result.fullPath = Paths.get(result.directory(), result.fileName(), result.fileExt());
        return result;
    }
```

is there another alternative, so that the `fullPath` field can be **final**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply have a Builder method that takes the full path and use a default value:

```
@AutoValue
abstract class PathExample {

  static Builder builder() {
    return new AutoValue_PathExample.Builder();
  }

  abstract String directory();
  abstract String fileName();
  abstract String fileExt();
  abstract Path fullPath();

  @AutoValue.Builder
  interface Builder {
    abstract Builder directory(String s);
    abstract Builder fileName(String s);
    abstract Builder fileExt(String s);
    abstract Builder fullPath(Path p);
    abstract PathExample autoBuild();
    public PathExample build() {
        fullPath(Paths.get(directory(), fileName(), fileExt()));
        return autoBuild();
    }
  }

}
```

This should be pretty safe since the constructor will be made private so there should be no situation in which an instance can be created without going through the `build()` method path unless you create your own static factory methods, in which case you can do the same thing.